# get the following to return all urls in a text file that have a specific format

Tags: java, gdata

This is more on the code I posted earlier.

I have got the following to return a single URL contained within all the XML data I pulled from YouTube gdata. I am now having trouble getting it to return all the URLs that fall within the specified layout.

This is the code that returns a single URL

```
while ((inputLine = sc.findWithinHorizon("www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HJ2fl4zbx0&amp;feature=youtube_gdata", 0)) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
```

Now, I need it to return all URLs that start with "www.youtube.com/watch?v=" and end with "&feature=youtube_gdata"

Alternatively, it would work perfectly if I could have it return just the next 11 characters after "www.youtube.com/watch?v="

Comment: regexp will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you could use something like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(
        "www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HJ2fl4zbx0&amp;feature=youtube_gdata");
String openStr = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
while (sc.hasNextLine() && (inputLine = sc.nextLine()) != null) {
    int pos = inputLine.indexOf(openStr);
    if (pos > -1) {
        pos += openStr.length();
        System.out.println(inputLine.substring(pos, pos + 11));
    }
}
```

Notice the above uses a single `String` Scanner, but the output is

```
9HJ2fl4zbx0
```

Comment: i never thought of using .hasNextLine in the loop. it works flawlessly thanks.